# How to put plt.text fields one above another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to add several text lines to the plot at the same ***x*** coordinate, one above another.
The problem is that ***y*** scale max is high, so if I put them literally one above another (so ***y*** for the 1st value is ***y*** for 2nd value + font size), they are so close that it's impossible to distinguish them from each other.
One solution is to multiply the gap by the scale. Or found out the rectangle that is used by previous line and calculate ***y*** using it. But then they won't be next to each other if I zoom the picture in...
Any scalable solutions, please? The text is auto-scaled somehow, are there an option for the gaps/***y*** axis?

```
x = <my calculated x value>
y = 6 * (n - i - 1) # where n - amount of lines, i - index of current text line
text = plt.text(x, y, text_drops, fontsize=6)
```

The next 2 pictures show the same part of the plot - in actual size and zoomed in.

This one shows actual scale: one cell has height of 50000

[image: Scaled so y cell is 25 points high]

This is zoomed in so one cell has height of 25

[image: Scaled so y cell is 25 points high]

UPD: Put Joooeey's suggestion in action in other way - worked for me:

```
x = <my calculated x value>
text = plt.text(x, 0, text_drops + i * '\n', fontsize=6) # where i - index of current  line
```

Comment: Put a sample data as example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one text field, separated by line breaks:

```
lines = ['drop start at 125989msg/sec',
         'drop start at 126169msg/sec',
         'drop start at 126381msg/sec']
multiline = '\n'.join(lines) # put in line breaks
texts = plt.text(x, y, multiline, horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='left')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could do it if I was sure that x coordinate is exactly the same for all lines. But it may be slightly different, and then I will draw more than 1 vertical line, close enough for text to interlap, but not obvious enough for user to understand what text corresponds to what line.